# Emit SourceMaps from tsconfig only for Dev

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to have a **tsconfig** sitting in my prod folder to only create sourcemaps if **process.env** is `development`?  I don't want sourcemaps created during my CI/CD build or pushed to production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tsconfig was not meant to have stuff like env in the file itself its just a simple json file. To do what you want you should be using your own config for each env aka `tsconfig.production.json`, `tsconfig.development.json`

You can then in your build pipeline use the `--project`/`--p` command when doing `tsc` to specify your location. So if you want only prod builds being created in your CI/CD then in your step on executing `tsc` you can just do `tsc -p ./tsconfig.production.json` where `./tsconfig.production.json` is your path to that file. If you want it to use your `env` itself most of the `CI/CD` lets you execute a different script depending on the `env` so again you just execute this one for prod builds.

Another quick note most people structure their tsconfig files to have a `base` file which say in this example `tsconfig.development.json` extends and so does `tsconfig.production.json`. In the `tsconfig.base.json` you have all the same main settings so you don't repeat yourself twice, with source maps turned off. Then in the `tsconfig.development.json` you can extend this file and turn source maps on, to still handle nice debugging when on development.

Anyway i hope this hopes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could specify it in the executing command

```
tsc --build --sourceMap false
```